# peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers not called after failed update

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral, cbperipheralmanager

Whenever I Disconnect and try to connect. I am not receiving peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers and first update only fails.

I am following the below steps

- Start Advertisement and establish connection with central.
- Now try to update value in queue. First one will be success and second update will fail. Then I will receive
  peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers, Then i'll continue update again.
- Close connection with central, Remove services and start advertisement again and add services. Then i'll receive
  peripheralManager : didSubscribeToCharacteristic again and now
  If I try to update (updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals) always it fails and i'll never receive peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers.

This behaviour is only with new iOS version 10.0.2. 
I am not facing this issue with older version of iOS like 9.3.3.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am in the same boat.

Comment: My app works great in iOS 9 but in iOS 10 I have the same issue.

Comment: No still waiting for response. If I am able to resolve i'll update.

Comment: Believe this is an iOS 10 issue. I wrote a bug to Apple about this. If you find anything else out please let me know.

Comment: A work around for this is to count the failures. And if its over 3-4 restart the service. I've only tested once so far, but this fixed it for me when I got into this weird state.

Comment: Thanks but I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Ya I am too actually. Sorry.

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: No. I am not able to resolve this. Without the help from apple or someone, I do not think will be able to resolve this issue.

Comment: I just got a workaround. Not sure that is a proper solution. If I re initialise CBPeripheralManager session then I was able to update value again.

Comment: When are you doing that?

Comment: Whenever I am doing stop advertisement, I'll do re initialise then again start advertisement.

Comment: I still have this issue in ios11. Can someone clarify, when you say reinitialise do you mean create a new instance of CBPeripheralManager? I'm doing that and it works. It feels a bit brute but...

Comment: @andy good that work around is working for you. So many people are facing the same issue but still no upvote for this question or proper solution for this question.

Comment: I'm still seeing the same issue in iOS 13...in 2020.  Surprising that this is still the only answer and that Apple hasn't fixed it yet.  I'll go search, but is there a particular bug report that I should be upvoting for Apple to see?